# DrawerLayout Access violation Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, drawerlayout

I have problem with drawingLayout in Windows Phone 8.1.
I implementet this layout on each pages in my app, and I initialized it on each pages.

On one site Im want to Navigate to the same site
for example:
I am on site named Page1 and I want to navigate to Page1 again with Frame.Navigate function.

When I have no DrawerLayout on pages it works, but when I have this layout it not works and app gives an error:
The program '[4608] app.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

What's the problem with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here this a blog that will help you implement side menu

http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.in/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html